# Is it correct to use "of" with "avoid"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I read a sentence which was:

> Mr Prasad said the unicast avoids of all shortcomings of the existing methods.

Is it correct to use "of" with "avoid"? I think we use "of" with "devoid".

Comment: From [Copies of the special reports of the Indian law commissioners:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+anomaly+will+be+avoided+of+having+one%22)  *the anomaly **will be avoided of having** one rate of duty on one side of a merely ideal line.* Which was clearly considered a valid usage in 1844 - by implication, in the British Parliament of the time, not just in "Indian English". ***But it wouldn't be considered valid today.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Your example is acceptable to my (educated American) ear.  Your example has "will be avoided" moved from the end of the sentence to the middle; "of having …" grammatically belongs with "the anomaly", not "avoided".

Comment: @Jasper: Fair point (my specific example is incredibly "awkward", but in principle it can be parsed). [*On the other hand, it offers that kind of interpretation of historical events and deeds **that avoids of refutation.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22avoids+of+refutation%22) But unfortunately, *that* example is relatively recent, so it doesn't really suit the point I wanted to make.

Comment: ...on the other *other* hand, here's [Cooke's translation of Hesiod (1810?)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+avoid+of+life+the+greatest+ill%22) *- And **to avoid of life** the greatest ill, Never may sloth prevail upon thy will.* There's definitely an "archaic feel" to the use of ***of*** in all these examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sentence is better read:

> Unicast **avoids all** shortcomings of the existing methods.

So, yeah, better to avoid the "of" with "avoid"

Comment: "better read" is a very appropriate turn of phrase.  Despite the fact the title warned me that the question was about the word "of", I omitted the word "of" the first time I read the example sentence.  (I speak American English, and I have taken a speed-reading class.)

Comment: "better" is an understatement! OP's use of ***of*** is *completely* unacceptable to *all* native Anglophones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That specific instance sounds off, yes. But the word _of_ can still be used idiomatically if we reorder the words: _Mr Prasad said the unicast **avoids all of the shortcomings** of existing methods._

Comment: @Jasper - what do you mean by "better read is a very appropriate turn of phrase?

Comment: @VishalGhulati -- A "turn of phrase" is a way of saying something.  In this context, "very appropriate" means "well-chosen" or "true in multiple ways".  I think that [Bhaskaran MU](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/89803) meant "the following example is better than the original post's example", which is true.  But as I noted, a native speaker might literally try to read the original example and only say the words in the following example.  So there are at least two ways that Bhaskaran's statement is true.

Comment: @J.R.: It wasn't hard for me to find [*to avoid of life the greatest ill*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+to+avoid+of+life%22) and [*but also to avoid of claims being presented*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22also+to+avoid+of+claims%22) in Google Books. My intuition tells me these usages might well have been considered valid a century or two ago, and it's well-known that Indian English has retained some aspects of syntax/vocabulary that have long died out in "mainstream" English. Your edit and comment nullify the relevance of this (but OP might be "IE-inclined").

Comment: Note that there's no problem keeping *of* if you change its position and add an article: *Unicast avoids all* ***of the*** *shortcomings of the existing models.*